# aggregate by date sequences and id variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, aggregate

Im strugling to aggregate hourly temperatures into 3-hourly while keeping the station ID.Here is the df:

| ID | Date | temp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1155 | 2012-01-01 00:00:00 | -0.8 |
| 1155 | 2012-01-01 01:00:00 | 0.1 |
| 1155 | 2012-01-01 02:00:00 | 0.5 |

and Im striving to get smth like:

| ID | Date | temp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1155 | 2012-01-01 | -0.2 |

Ive elaborated this code:

```
library(dplyr)
  Temp_3h<- df %>%
    group_by(ID)%>%
    aggregate(.,by=list(Date=cut(as.POSIXct(df$Date), "3 hour")),mean)
```

but beside the "temp" variable it also tend to aggregate IDs (categorical), so they become NAs. And I dont know how to integrate ID into "by=" argument. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `floor_date`/`ceiling_date` to combine timestamp every 3 hours into one and take average of `temp` values for each `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

Temp_3h <- df %>%
  group_by(ID, Date = floor_date(ymd_hms(Date), '3 hours')) %>%
  summarise(temp = mean(temp, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')

Temp_3h
```

Comment: Hey @Ronak Shah, it works! Many thanx

Answer (score 2):

I actually like the `cut` approach.

```
d |>
  transform(date_s=cut(as.POSIXct(d$Date), breaks="3 hours")) |>
  with(aggregate(list(mn_temp=temp), list(date=date_s, ID=ID), FUN=mean))
#                  date   ID     mn_temp
# 1 2012-01-01 00:00:00 1155 -0.06666667
# 2 2012-01-01 03:00:00 1155  0.56666667
# 3 2012-01-01 06:00:00 1155  0.93333333
# 4 2012-01-01 09:00:00 1155  3.70000000
```

If instead of the start time we rather want to display the end of the time interval, we could do

```
d |>
  transform(date_s=cut(
    as.POSIXct(d$Date), breaks="3 hours", 
    labels=(as.POSIXct(Date) + 10800)[(seq(Date) - 1) %% 3 == 0])) |>
  with(aggregate(list(mn_temp_lst3=temp), list(date=date_s, ID=ID), FUN=mean))
#                  date   ID mn_temp_lst3
# 1 2012-01-01 03:00:00 1155  -0.06666667
# 2 2012-01-01 06:00:00 1155   0.56666667
# 3 2012-01-01 09:00:00 1155   0.93333333
# 4 2012-01-01 12:00:00 1155   3.70000000
```

---

*Data*

```
d <- structure(list(ID = c(1155L, 1155L, 1155L, 1155L, 1155L, 1155L, 
1155L, 1155L, 1155L, 1155L), Date = c("2012-01-01 00:00:00", 
"2012-01-01 01:00:00", "2012-01-01 02:00:00", "2012-01-01 03:00:00", 
"2012-01-01 04:00:00", "2012-01-01 05:00:00", "2012-01-01 06:00:00", 
"2012-01-01 07:00:00", "2012-01-01 08:00:00", "2012-01-01 09:00:00"
), temp = c(-0.8, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.2, 3.7
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Upvote but `cut(as.POSIXct(d$Date), breaks="3 hours", etc)` seems more intuitive and avoids the call to `transform/factor`. The pipe-to-`with` idea alone deserves an upvote on its own,.

Comment: And if the 1st `transform` is `date = droplevels(.)`, you can pipe directly to `with(aggregate(temp ~ date + ID, FUN = mean))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thx, and you're right, I've changed that (somehow `cut.Date` didn't work before).

Answer (score 1):

You could floor the dates and use the `group_by` and `summarize` functions:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
summarise(group_by(df, ID, Date = floor_date(ymd_hms(Date), '3 hours')), first(Date), first(ID), sum(temp))
```

Output:

```
  first(Date) first(ID) sum(temp)
1  2012-01-01      1155      -0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(df1)[, .(temp = mean(temp, na.rm = TRUE)),
    .(ID, Date = floor_date(ymd_hms(Date), '3 hours'))]
```